# Kafka consumers from two partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In kafka I need to consume a topic with two partitions from two consumers (partition 1 to consumer 1 and partition 2 to consumer 2) using Java.

### This is my Producer Code

```
public class KafkaClientOperationProducer {

    KafkaClientOperationConsumer kac = new KafkaClientOperationConsumer();

    public void initiateProducer(ClientOperation clientOperation,
        ClientOperationManager activityManager,Logger logger) throws Exception {


    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094");
    props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    Producer<String, ClientOperation> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

    try{
    ProducerRecord<String, ClientOperation> record = new ProducerRecord<String, ClientOperation>(
            topicName, key, clientOperation);

    producer.send(record);

    }
    finally{
    producer.flush();
    producer.close();
    kac.initiateConsumer(activityManager);//Calling Consumer
    }
}
}
```

### This is my Consumer code

```
    public class KafkaClientOperationConsumer{

    String topicName = "CA_Topic";
    String groupName = "CA_TopicGroup";
    public  void initiateConsumer(ClientOperationManager activityManager) throws Exception {



    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094");
    props.put("group.id", groupName);
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    KafkaConsumer<String, ClientOperation> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));               

        ConsumerRecords<String, ClientOperation> records = consumer.poll(100);
        try{
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, ClientOperation> record : records) {    
            activityManager.save(record.value());//saves data in database

        }}
    finally{
        consumer.close();}
    }
    }
```

The above code is working fine for single consumer not for multiple consumers
The clientOperation is a object which holds data about client operation.
    The partition number is three(which you can see from the code) ,
When i tried to call initiateConsumer using thread i.e..(ExecutorService executor) I'm getting Duplicate values in database
    Please change my code so that i can consume CA_Topic using two consumers,I can't use two JVM's due to memory problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: add more details about what you have try. The purpose of your problem etcetera

Comment: You just need to run two instances of consumer having same consumer group id. Refer to any java consumer code

Comment: @Sourav Gulati ,That is my problem I'm unable to run two instance of Consumer.java Parallely like threads , Thanks for your reply .

Comment: not multithreaded, just run two separate instances of your consumer app in two JVMs and they will automatically balance the partitions evenly amongst themselves

Comment: Unable why? Because of errors or you don't know how? Please edit your question to include the code you've written thus far

Comment: Please share the code.There must be some mistake

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must use KafkaConsumer.assign method. Here a little example:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "ip:port");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");

final Consumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition("topic", 0); // topic name and partition id to be assigned for this consumer. in other consumer configurations this value must be any value other than 0
List<TopicPartition> partitionList = new ArrayList<TopicPartition>();
partitionList.add(topicPartition);
consumer.assign(partitionList); // in this line, 0. partition assigning to this consumer
```

You can see detail in documentation of Kafka: https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#assign(java.util.Collection)